# How to solve botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, tox

I have a GitHub action which is running a tox.ini file. One of the steps of the action is to connect to aws and the last step is to run tox

```
- name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.key }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.secret_key }}
        aws-region: ${{ secretes.region }}
- name: Run tox
      run: tox
```

And for some reason my action fails with the following error `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`
I'm not sure why this is happening especially since the aws configuration step is passing in the action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you still get this error after setting credentials is because the `aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials` sets environment variables and tox, by default, does not pass along env vars. You can tell tox to pass the variables in your `tox.ini` file. Something like this:

```
[testenv]
passenv = AWS_*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This issue had been bothering me for a few days.